# Python - get probability/percentage value if string exists in text

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

I'm trying to figure out if there is any Python library which allows me to get the percentage value of probability if the string that I'm looking for exists in text or if there is any similar.

To get it more clearly, here is the example:

My string is **'Company Ltd'** and in text it exists but under the phrase **'Company Limited'**. 
The other example, **'Boeing BG'** and in text it is present by **'Boeing B.G.'**

Is there any way for to get percentage value/probability that it exists in text or not?

Answer (score 3):

A candidate for your search is the  [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) library

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
fuzz.ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
```

will print 97

Comment: That is fine, but what if I have longer text longer text and I have to check if the string I'm looking for or similar one exists there? Is it possible with this library?

Comment: in case of a total match it will output 100, so you should handle it in code: the library has many features, i suggest you take a look at them https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy, it will come handy

Comment: it is fine, but when I compare a single word or short sentence to the whole text to check the percentage probability of occurrence this word or similar one in text, I'm getting the really small value. I can use this, after spliting the text but it isn't the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: a bit of NLP reminder, the fuzzywuzzy uses Levenshtein_distance ,  to match second string, so when the searched text gets bigger the value (probability ) will get smaller, what i suggest to do, is doing a moving search in your text, e.g.  you are searching for has length 5 add a constant ( 2, 3 change it and see the one that gives you best results ) and loop throught the whole text;
first iteration you search inside the x = 5 + constant first words, then you move the sentence by 1 word, and store the result in a list; tweak the approach according to your needs